# Is there a way to check update for particular npm package using rss/atom or other similar way?

Tags: node.js, npm, rss, atom-feed

I found only this thread when an user ask similar question but without answer. ( https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/issues/17 )

I know two sites that are repositories of NPM packages:

- https://www.npmjs.com
- http://libraries.io

And I can't find a way to obtain an rss for single package in a way like it is done for github or sourceforge:

- `https://github.com/<author_name>/<package_name>/releases.atom`
- `http://sourceforge.net/projects/<project_name>/rss?limit=20`

And yes, i know that I might check what is the github repository for given NPM and do it that way, but I specifically ask for a way to reach this info from some kind of NMP repository that tracks if a given package changed its git address (not necessarily these two I added here as example.)

It is hard to find these tricks by google because it thinks I'm searching for some kind of NPM package that deals with RSS/ATOM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've recently added a release atom feed to all packages on libraries.io, simply add `/versions.atom` to the end of any project page url, for example:

https://libraries.io/npm/node-sass/versions.atom

With npm modules it should never be more than 10 minutes delayed in showing the newest version.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also add a changelog in the description for every entry, just as they do it in drupal: https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release/feed , it would be a nice timesaver.

Comment: I'm working on that feature, keep an eye on this github issue to see when it ships: https://github.com/librariesio/support/issues/17

Comment: I'm getting 403 errors from the feed for `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` - https://libraries.io/npm/@mapbox%2Fmapbox-sdk/versions.atom

Answer (score 3):

You need to hit your requests against an [NPM registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry), i.e. https://registry.npmjs.org/-/rss.

For single packages, the URL should be https://registry.npmjs.org/-/rss/browserfiy, but the responses aren't being constructed correctly at the time of writing.

Alternatively, you could go for a JSON response, i.e. https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify. For a more programmatic way of accessing package details, you can use [`npm-registry-client`](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client).

Comment: Yes, but these are all packages at once, is there any api/modification available to this link so I can filter it down to single package, that is without running any scraping software on my local computer ?

Comment: Updated the answer with specifics on how to access the details of a single package

Comment: "at the time of writing" - is somebody working on it now, or was just left years ago ?

Comment: There is support and the server is responding with a  `200` https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/blob/8fac05145dd30630519dcd33ab9ff2743c932b72/registry/rewrites.js#L29. I cannot say definitively why the expected content isn't transmitted--other public registry instances I've found do not have any RSS support.